# How do i get max and circulating supply of a Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, money-supply

Hi how do i get the circulating supply for etc Bitcoin, Ethereum and so on?

I am not talking about coinmarketcap's API i want to get these data myself.

Is there any tutorials on how to do this anywhere and can i do it with an automated script in PHP?

Comment: There is no one database that stores reliable data for all the coins. You would have to look at the source code for each coin yourself to see what the caps are (for now), or whitepapers, or else trust what other people who have done that tell you, such as coinmarketcap or google.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to download your desired blockchain and find all of the UTXOs and their value, add all of them together find the total circulating supply. I would personally do it using python.